Definition of global supersymmetry on curved spacetimes and use of constant spinor fields
According to "Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians" (Deligne et al.), we call theories supersymmetric if their action functional is invariant under the action of a super Poincaré algebra on the space of extremals. The odd part of a super Poincaré algebra is given by a direct sum of real spinor representations.
Is this definition valid for arbitrary, non-Minkowski spacetimes as well?
Usually, when proving that such a theory is indeed supersymmetric, the supersymmetry transformation is defined by the action of a constant spinor field - Does that mean that the spinor representation is isomorphic to the space of constant spinor fields with respect to the spin connection induced by the Levi-Civita connection? In this case, could someone prove this isomorphism, preferably in a coordinate free manner?
It makes sense to think of the (super-)Poincaré transformations on each point in spacetime separately, so this would explain why we still talk about Poincaré symmetry even though the spacetime could be curved.
Reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604151

Hi anonymous250. Welcome to Phys.SE. Just to make sure we are on the same page: How do you define Poincare transformations on a non-Minkowski spacetime?

As an action of the Poincaré group. While the spacetime manifold itself is not Minkowski, each tangent space is. The fields take values in (projective) representations of the corresponding Poincaré group: E.g., the spinor field $\psi$ is a smooth section of the spinor bundle. As each fibre is (canonically) isomorphic to a spinor representation $S$, $\psi(p)\in S$, so a representation of the Poincaré group on the space of sections is defined pointwise. This is what I meant in the fourth paragraph by it still making sense to talk about Poincaré transformations.

Constant spinor fields will explicitly break a global supersymmetry in a curved spacetime. However, instead of constant spinors, one can use Killing spinor fields on a fiber bundle, in that case local supersymmetry can be defined properly. It is called supergravity.

@OktayDoğangün, thanks for the comment! However, I am looking for the definition of global supersymmetry, not supergravity. Would you be so kind as to define supersymmetry on curved spacetime?

By the way: I am referring to this paper in which it was just stated that the supersymmetry is generated by constant spinor fields. Of course, parallel spinors are Killing spinors, so it could be a coincidence that it happened to be parallel ones for SYM

The covariantly constant or parallel spinors arise as follows:
Suppose we start with a superalgebra with supercharge $Q$. Then an infinitesimal transformation by that supercharge is generated by $\bar\epsilon Q$, where $\epsilon$ is a spinor. The theory can only have unbroken symmetry under $Q$ if $\bar\epsilon Q \lvert 0\rangle = 0$ for the vacuum of the theory, and so in particular the expectation value of $[\bar\epsilon Q, \phi]$ must vanish for all fields $\phi$.
In particular, the variation of the gravitino field $\psi$ is:
$$ \delta \psi = [\bar\epsilon Q, \psi_\mu] = \nabla_\mu \epsilon + \text{terms in field strengths}$$
and in a fluxless background the condition that this vanishes is therefore $\nabla_\mu \epsilon = 0$, i.e. the condition that $\epsilon$ be a covariantly constant spinor. Note that there are in principle further conditions from other field variations but physics usually makes assumptions that make those vanish anyway.
So what remains of the super part of the superalgebra we start with - which may be the super-Poincaré algebra or an extended version or anything else - is the subset of the algebra generated by the $\bar\epsilon Q$ for the covariantly constant spinors. In flat Minkowski space, we have enough such spinors to generate the full algebra.
Note that adding fluxes back in or dropping any of the other assumptions that make the rest of the field variations vanish may lead to supersymmetric theories on backgrounds without covariantly constant spinors where $\epsilon$ has to obey more complicated equations.
